# What is the number of 2-regular, 2-uniform hypergaphs on n labeled nodes?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A hypergraph is a graph whose edges are subsets of the vertices.  A 2-regular hypergraph is such that every vertex is in exactly 2 edges.  A 2-uniform hypergraph is such that every edge contains 2 vertices.

I wrote an inefficient Mathematica code that I think returns the  2-regular,2-uniform hypergrpahs but only up to 8 vertices.  The number of these hypergraphs matches Sloane's OEIS A001205, for n<=8.  The sequence A001205 counts the number of labeled 2-regular graphs.  Is there a way to show that this is (or is not) the number of 2-regular,2-uniform hypergraphs?

n = 5; Select[KSubsets[KSubsets[Range[n], 2], n], 
Sort[Flatten[#]] == Sort[Flatten[{Range[n], Range[n]}]] &]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose that this follows by inspection. If every edge contains two vertices we have the class of ordinary undirected graphs (edges on or off according to subset present or not). We then require that every vertex has degree two, so we get a set of undirected cycles with species $\mathfrak{P}(\mathfrak{D}_{\ge 3}(\mathcal{Z}))$ and EGF (dihedral symmetry $\mathfrak{D}$ as opposed to rotational symmetry $\mathfrak{C}$ on the cycles)

$$G(z) = \exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 3} \frac{z^q}{2q}\right)
= \exp\left(-\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{4} 
+ \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{z^q}{2q}\right)
\\ = \exp\left(-\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{4} \right)
\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\\ = \exp\left(-\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{4} \right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}.$$

This yields the sequence

$$1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 12, 70, 465, 3507, 30016, 286884,\ldots$$

which is indeed [OEIS A001205](https://oeis.org/A001205).

Comment: Yes. Of course. A 2-uniform hypergraph IS a graph.  Thank you!.

Comment: You're welcome. The OEIS entry is an interesting one, offering a manageable number of links to various contributions from analytical combinatorics.